# How to use an Entity Framework navigation property with MySqlConnector when some of the navigation keys are nullable?

Tags: c#, entity-framework-5, mysql-connector

Here is a sample setup:

```
public class Car
{
 public int CarId { get; set; }
 public int? PreviousOwnerId { get; set; }
 public PreviousOwner PreviousOwner { get; set; }
}

public PreviousOwner
{
 public int PreviousOwnerId { get; set; }
 public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

and then the query:

```
var cars = db.Cars.Where( c => c.PreviousOwner.Name = "Stack" ).ToList();
```

However, I get an error because some of the cars have a null `PreviousOwnerId`. The inner exception reads `"Unknown column 'Extent1.PreviousOwnerId' in 'where clause'"`.

Note: This is using the .net mysql connector

Answer (score -1):

The issue you have here is that your navigation property doesnt appear to have enough configuration information. (such as modelbuilder config or attribute config) which is required when using non-standard names for PK/Fks. I would recommend reading my article on how navigation properties work here: http://blog.staticvoid.co.nz/2012/7/17/entity_framework-navigation_property_basics_with_code_first

I imagine you will be needing something like the following (example uses modelbuilder):

```
modelBuilder.Entity<Car>().HasOptional(c=>c.PreviousOwner).WithMany().HasForeignKey(c=>c.PreviousOwnerId);
```

Comment: I added this to my onmodelcreating: `modelBuilder.Entity<Car>().HasOptional(c => c.PreviousOwner);` and still got the same error.

Comment: Same error with the edit you made. Perhaps it is because this is strictly 1 to 1 (and not 1 to many).

Comment: @travisj take a look at your actual database i imagine the FK will look something like PreviousOwner_PreviousOwnerId, if this is the case rename it to PreviousOwnerId or regen/migrate your database

Comment: That is not the case. -1 for suggesting to migrate a database without any basis.

Comment: Note also, that this is the standardized naming convention for using entity framework's navigation properties.

Comment: @travisj the model builder effects both schema and mapping, for this reason its reasonable to expect that if the model was incorrectly mapped origionally regnereation may be required. It seems you feel I am not qualified to answer your question, good luck finding someone else to solve your problem.

Comment: Model building is not just for code first. It also defines how entity framework will design it's structure to be sent to a SQL generator. The structure of the map is what is important here, because navigational properties are *virtual* (i.e. not in the database). I sincerely hope you do not tell others to migrate their databases with such ease.

Comment: This issue is related to `mysqlconnector` which was explicitly stated in the question. Your answer only works when using the `System.Data.SqlClient` provider and is unfortunately not applicable in this scenario.